# how to convert and play a .h263 file?

Tags: c++, asterisk

I am working on ubuntu. I have a file.h263 and I don't know how to play it. I've tried ffmpeg -f msg0001.h263 -i file.avi but it didn;t work. Need some help please. I want to convert file.h263 in .avi or mp2 in order to play the file in an android phone. Got any advices? It would be best to have a c++ code. but i didn't find any example, nothing at all.

Please help. If you have a piece of code that does this I would appreciate.
Thx

Comment: Where did the file come from?  What application produced it?

Comment: the file.h263 it;s an asterisk voicemail file

Comment: H263 is a video codec. Why would voicemail (presumably audio only) be encoded in H263?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to play H263 file and convert it to AVI as the following:

```
ffplay -i file.h263
ffmpeg -i file.h263 file.avi
```

For android playback you can keep video stream in H.263 and convert the file to 3GPP (.3gp) or MPEG-4 file format or change file format and codec to MPEG-4 and H.264. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i file.h263 -vcodec copy -f 3gp file-h263.3gp
ffmpeg -i file.h263 -vcodec h264 -f mp4 file-h264.mp4
```

See [Android supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for more information.

Comment: thx for your reply. and which is the best the 3gp or the mp4?

Comment: The choice would depend on the devices you need to support. 3gp is quite limited in terms of bit rates and resolutions. Being newer and more flexible MP4 could be a better choice.

Comment: what do you mean by validing the input file? I did play the file.h263 with the vlc program and it works ok

Comment: Does ffmpeg recognize it as a valid file? Can you play it with ffplay?

Answer (score 0):

.h263 is old yet great format, and if your software player uses HW accelration to play video that majority of old videocards (including Nvidia, ATI) will provide you HW accelration for video playback for .h263 format files... now various use .h264 format... thus try to convert videos to .h264 format instead of avi...

i think what you are facing is  a extension delima .... try renaming it to MP4, then various player will play it without problems..

you can also use vlc.. one of the best video players ever...

Beside GStreamer can play H263 files , and with gstreamer pipelines you can convert various format on flies...

though i usually use [Handbreak](http://handbrake.fr/) to convert video files /DVD's, and it is available on windows, Mac as well as on linux ....

P.S. in Gstreamer, you might need to install plugins, install all 2... good, bad and ugly plugin. i am not sure in which .h263 comes in, but must be in one of these three......

Comment: I've renames the file .MP4 but i couldn't play it with Movie PLayer. I will install VLC and try it again. The error on Movie PLayer was: could not determine type of stream. What shoould I do next? do you have a c/c++ code that convert a s file.h263 into an mp4 file? I would like to specify that the file that i have with the .h263 extensions is an asterisk voicemail file.

Comment: gstreamer can be used in pipelines from comand prompt too, so you do not need c++ code for doing the job, a small shell script will also work.. :) 

I will shoot some example from home, where i can check the correct pipeline for your usecase... in case if you want to try yourself..  here an intro to gstreamer pipelines..

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Example_GStreamer_Pipelines

Comment: ok. thx. i am watiting for an example. I am going to look over the link you sent. Thx:) As I've told you I did change the extension of h263 with mp4 but i can't play the video, not even with VLC.